# strip defined character from string

Tags: php, mysql, strip

im having a odd problem os my website, i have a script that records all the searchs and insert those search words on database, the problem is that since search engine robots started sneaking around my website, they make my script to produce search keywords like "search keywords////////////////////////////////////////////////"
I want to strip that characteres ( ////////// ) before indexed on mysql.

This is what i have:

```
$search=htmlspecialchars($_GET['load']); 
$say=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM madvideo WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('*$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"); 
$saydim=mysql_num_rows($say);
$count = $saydim;
$page = !empty($_GET["page"]) ? intval($_GET["page"]) : 1;
$s = ($page-1)*$perpage;
$sayfasayisi=ceil($count/$perpage);
if(ayaral("Arananlar-Kaydet")=="1") {
$ekle=cevir($search);
@mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) values ('$search','$ekle',now()) "); }
```

The variable " $search " will call the search word, and i dont know whats the strip syntax i have to use to strip that nasty ///////// character.

EDIT: the code that creates the words is this:

```
$vtitle = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", ' ', $vtitle); 

$words = explode(' ', $vtitle); 

$k = count($words); 
$k3 = ceil($k/3); 

$new = array(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$k; $i+=$k3) { 
    $new[] = join(' ', array_slice($words,$i, $k3)); 
} 
$tag1 = $new[0]; 
$tag2 = $new[1]; 
$tag3 = $new[2];
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they're being deprecated. Checkout `PDO` or `mysqli_` and use prepared statements. Meanwhile `str_replace('/','',$stirng);` should work

Comment: Use post forms, not get forms. Otherwise you are asking for such trouble your own, looks like you re-linked the search and made a mistake with that. Also what did you try so far, you only have given a description of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to remove from end of the string as follows:

```
TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM <string>)

@mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) 
values (TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM '$search'),'$ekle',now())")
```

To trim from both beginning and ending, use following

```
TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM <string>)

@mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) 
values (TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM '$search'),'$ekle',now())")
```

To remove all occurences of the string use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function as follows:

```
REPLACE(<string>, '/', '')

@mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) 
values (REPLACE('$search', '/',''),'$ekle',now())")
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks shubhansh, that worked for the /// at the end of the text, but i noticed that this issue also happens on text that have the /// characteres like: word/´s////. How can i remove all the //// characteres? Regards

Comment: I tested /////word and the characteres still remain. This is really wierd, i cant figure it out why these //// are being produced when the bots hit the page. i will post my script that creates these words. Thanks

Comment: I just checked but it turns me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /usr/home/myuser/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/search.php on line 30 i tryed to fix it by removing one " but dont work. Thanks for your patience EDIT: the line of the output error is the same we are working here

Comment: Just a dumb question, im not using the first line you provided: TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM <string>) because it was trowing an error, so i removed and your first fix was working, this last one is giving me the error i mentioned on previous reply

Comment: Use single quotes, in place of double quotes, i forgot you are using PHP. I have edited my answer check  that out...

Comment: I did as you mentioned but now is not working at all, theres no output error but just dont replace the characteres. What a bummer

Comment: Sorry, its working properly, i was testing in a old php file. Thanks so much for your efforts on trying to help me. You saved my week. Sincerely

Comment: I just accepted yours, thanks. Please tell me, if i need to replace more characteres how should i use? i was trying you fix this way: @mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) 
values (REPLACE('$search', '/\',''),'$ekle',now())"); } but dont replace the \ characteres only the /.

Comment: You will be required to do mysql_real_escape, if you are having '\' in string, '\' is mysql escape character. After that you can do as follows: @mysql_query("insert into tag (baslik,tr,tarih) values (REPLACE(REPLACE('$search', '\\',''),'/',''),'$ekle',now())"); }

Comment: Is it working if you don't use mysql_real_escape_string? Check if return value from mysql_real_escape_string is not FALSE? Try using mysql_escape_string or addslashes function? try debugging value of $search after mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: I really tought the problem was at the end of word, but i just noticed this only happens on words that have the ´ accent, like word´s it will turn word\\\\\\´s. I think im going to drop this option. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Real example...

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['str'])) {

    $search = $_REQUEST['str'];

    $ser_chk = strpos($search, "/");
    if ($ser_chk > -1) {
    $search = str_replace("/", "", $search);
    }

}

?>

<h1><?php print $search; ?></h1>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" size="100" value="search keywords////////////////////////////////////////////////" name="str" />
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

LINK TO TEST: http://simplestudio.rs/tsto.php

At least do:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
```

Also you can check for that characters and if founded just replace them with empty string.

```
$ser_chk = strpos($search, "/");
if ($ser_chk > -1) {
$search = str_replace("/", "", $search);
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you tested?

Comment: Well i tested your whole code since the variables are the same im using. but the /// characters are still not being stripped :S

Answer (score 1):

If the `/` characters appear always at the end of the `$search`, you can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) using the second (optional) parameter:

```
$search = "search keywords////////////////////////////////////////////////";
$search = rtrim($search, '/ ');
echo $search; // prints 'search keywords'
```

Comment: They appear at the end, and when the text have the ` symbol. ie: word/´s. Thanks Carlos

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/\//";
$string = "////search";
$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

The flexible solution for character repetition will be a regular expression.

```
$output = preg_replace('/\/[\/]+/', '/'. $input);
```

It will handle any number of "/" and replace it with a single "/".

Comment: I need to remove all the / because in the current environment its not suposed to have this. I Appreciate your time